# make : rule call rule

Tags: makefile

In a makefile, can I call a rule from another rule?

Similar to:

```
rule1:
        echo "bye"
rule2:
        date
rule3:
        @echo "hello"
        rule1
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Either use dependencies or recursive making to connect from one rule to another.

Dependencies would be done like this (though the order will be different):

```make
rule1:
        echo "bye"
rule2:
        date
rule3: rule1
        @echo "hello"
```

Recursive make would be done like this (though it does involve a subprocess):

```make
rule1:
        echo "bye"
rule2:
        date
rule3:
        @echo "hello"
        $(MAKE) rule1
```

Neither is perfect; indeed, with recursive make you can get into significant problems if you build a loop. You also probably ought to add a `.PHONY` rule so as to mark those rules above as synthetic, so that a stray `rule1` (etc.) in the directory won't cause confusion.

Answer (score 35):

Just add a new rule with the ordering you want..

```
rule1:
        echo "bye"
rule2:
        date
rule3:
        @echo "hello"

rule4: rule3 rule1
```

Comment: Imho this is a much nicer solution than the other answers.

Comment: Simple - I like it.

Comment: This won't impose the ordering. It will just assure that rule1 and rule3 are done before rule4, no assurance on ordering

Comment: I second CristianDonosoC's comment. Since there is no ordering between rule1 and rule3 here, doing a parallel make (`make -j2`, for instance) will give you indeterminant execution order.

Comment: There is a way to run pre-requisites in a specified order: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html – Using this, rule4 should be: `rule4: | rule3 rule1`

Answer (score 20):

Makefiles are not procedural; "rules" are not like functions.  That said, you can specify that one rule is a prerequisite of another:

```
rule1:
    @echo "Rule 1"

rule2: rule1
    @echo "Rule 2"
```

If you do `make rule2`, you should see:

```
Rule 1
Rule 2
```

Comment: Frustratingly, though, you can't get "Rule 2\nRule 1" out of it

Comment: @Tomalak: Depends on your definition of "frustrating"!  Once the OP accepts that rules are not procedural functions, then there's not much to be frustrated about.

Comment: It is not answering the question. It should output Rule 2 and then Rule 1. This is what the author want to achieve.

Comment: @nosbor - the OP does not state what specific output is desired.

Answer (score 5):

There are two advanced functions in GNU Make which can do this, although it should only be used in extenuating circumstances. This SO is top rated in google.

Rule prerequisites are more recommended, but sometimes you need a post-requisite.

[GNU Make Call function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html)

[GNU Make Eval function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html)

Essentially, Eval lets you build targets on the fly, and Call allows function like "defines" to be created.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is:

```
ifeq (a, b)
    build_target:=one
else
    build_target:=two
endif

mytarget: $(build_target)
```