# How do you call a rule that involves `%` from another rule in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I have the following makefile snippet to compile my C++ project.

```
obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now I want to link the `.o` files. But I want to be able to just call the rule name of the link, like `make build/main`, in order to compile AND link.

Neither this:

```
build/main: $(wildcard obj/*.o)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

works, as it only links and does not compile, as I would expect by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8646714/3560202);

nor this:

```
build/main: obj/%.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

with the error:

> No rule to make target 'obj/%.o', needed by 'build/main'.  Stop.

even though it is needed.

Comment: The `build/main: $(wildcard obj/*.o)` won't work, because the wildcard will be expanded when the rule is first read (before the .o's are built, and before they exist on the filesystem, so it would expand to empty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst src/%.cpp, obj/%.o, $(SOURCES))

build/main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Does `SOURCES` expand to `src/main.cpp src/other.cpp` or `main.cpp other.cpp`?

Comment: @kim366: You can see for yourself: put `$(info it expands to $(SOURCES))` after the assignment.